# Three independent events, $E$, $F$ and $G$ occur with probability $\frac12$, $\frac13$ and $\frac14$ respectively.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least one of the three events occur?

Comment: What's the probability that **none** of them occur?

Comment: Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Maybe we can add the combinations in which the events can occur. For instance, E and F occurring + F and G occurring + E & F & G occurring so on.

Comment: That method seems too tedious.  Try it and see how much arithmetic it requires.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(E) = \frac 12$$

$$P(E') = 1 - \frac 12$$

$$P(E') = \frac 12$$

$$P(F) = \frac 13$$

$$P(F') = 1 - \frac 13$$

$$P(F') = \frac 23$$

$$P(G) = \frac 14$$

$$P(G') = 1 - \frac 14$$

$$P(G') = \frac 34$$

Probability that at least one event occurs = 1 - Probability that none of the events occur

$$= 1 - P(E') \cdot P(F') \cdot P(G')$$

$$= 1 - \frac 12 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 34$$

Comment: Can the problem be done without finding complements and simply 'adding' the given probabilities?

Comment: @KhushwantSingh by "simply adding" no, but by adding and then subtracting and adding again as per inclusion-exclusion, yes.  See my answer above.  Remember that $Pr(E\cup F)\neq Pr(E)+Pr(F)$ unless $E$ and $F$ are *mutually exclusive* (*or more correctly, their intersection is an "almost impossible" event*) so "simply adding" isn't correct to do in most situations.

Comment: I think it can be done using addition only with 3 cases. First only one of them solve it, second two on them solve it, third all three solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: Inclusion Exclusion.

$P(E\cup F\cup G)$ corresponds to the probability at least one of the three occur:

By inclusion exclusion this expands to:

$$P(E\cup F\cup G)=P(E)+P(F)+P(G)-P(E\cap F)-P(E\cap G)-P(F\cap G)+P(E\cap F\cap G)$$

Each of the above terms on the right should be easily calculated using the independence assumption.

> $=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$